# How do I prove these matrices have the same rank?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $n \times m$ matrix and let $T_A : \mathbb{R}^m → \mathbb{R}^n$ be the linear transformation $T_A(x)=Ax.$
Also let $B$ be an invertible $m × m$ matrix and let $C$ be an invertible $n × n$ matrix.

How do I prove that prove that the matrices A and CAB have the same rank?

I was thinking of using the rank-nullity theorem but I don't see how that would work.

Comment: In what way is the information about the linear transform involved?

Comment: Welcome to MSE, it is recommended on  this website to share your own attempts,  then others can help you.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $AB$ will have exactly the same image (column-space) as $A$, and $C(AB)$ will have exactly the same kernel (null-space) as $AB$.

Once you prove these facts, the rank-nullity theorem tells you that $C(AB)$ has the same rank as $AB$, whcih has the same rank as $A$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

If you show that $rank(A) = rank(CA) = rank(AB)$, your result follows.

One way is to remember that rank has to do with the number of linearly independent columns or rows in a matrix. When you multiply by invertible matrix (i.e. all rows linearly independent), what does that do to original number of linearly independent rows?